# Appwrite + React: Blog app: Failed to construct 'URL': Invalid URL

Tags: javascript, reactjs, authentication, appwrite, invalid-url

I am using **appwrite** with **react** and I am having a **problem logging in** or **signing up** users.

When a users click the button he should see the home page, edit post and add post routes.
But I'm getting an error in *Failed to construct 'URL': Invalid URL*

Here is the error message:
[console message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KjqYr.png)

**Below is the code for my appwrite.auth.js file:**

```
import conf from "../conf/conf.js"
import { Client, Account, ID } from "appwrite";

export class AuthService {
    client = new Client();
    account;

    constructor() {
        this.client
        .setEndpoint(conf.appwriteUrl)
        .setProject(conf.appwriteProjectId)
        this.account = new Account(this.client)
    }

    async createAccount({email, password, name}){
        try {
            const userAccount = await this.account.create(ID.unique(), email, password, name)
            if (userAccount) {
                return this.login({email, password})
            } else {
                return userAccount
            }
        } catch (error) {
            throw error
        }
    }

    async login({email, password}){
        try {
            return await this.account.createEmailSession(email, password)
        } catch (error) {
            throw error
        }
    }

    async getCurrentUser(){
        try {
            return await this.account.get()
        } catch (error) {
            console.log("Appwrite service :: getCurrentUser() :: ", error)
        }
        return null
    }

    async logout(){
        try {
            await this.account.deleteSessions()
        } catch (error) {
            console.log("Appwrite service :: logout() :: ", error);
        }
    }
}

const authService = new AuthService()

export default authService
```

**Below is my appwrite/config.js file for reference:**

```
import conf from "../conf/conf";
import { Client, Databases, Storage, Query, ID } from "appwrite";


export class Service {
    client = new Client()
    databases;
    bucket;

    constructor(){
        this.client
        .setEndpoint(conf.appwriteUrl)
        .setProject(conf.appwriteProjectId)
        this.databases = new Databases(this.client)
        this.bucket = new Storage(this.client)
    }

    async getPost(slug) {
        try {
            return await this.databases.getDocument(conf.appwriteDatabaseId, conf.appwriteCollectionId, slug)
        } catch (error) {
            console.log("Appwrite service :: getPost() :: ", error)
            return false
        }
    }

    async getPosts(queries = [Query.equal("status", "active")]) {
        try {
            return await this.databases.listDocuments(conf.appwriteDatabaseId, conf.appwriteCollectionId, queries)
        } catch (error) {
            console.log("Appwrite service :: getPosts() :: ", error)
            return false
        }
    }

    async createPost({title, slug, content, featuredImage, status, userId}) {
        try {
            return await this.databases.createDocument(conf.appwriteDatabaseId, conf.appwriteCollectionId, slug, {title, content, featuredImage, status, userId})
        } catch (error) {
            console.log("Appwrite service :: createPost() :: ", error)
            return false
        }
    }

    async updatePost(slug, {title, content, featuredImage, status}) {
        try {
            return await this.databases.updateDocument(conf.appwriteDatabaseId, conf.appwriteCollectionId, slug, {title, content, featuredImage, status})
        } catch (error) {
            console.log("Appwrite service :: updatePost() :: ", error)
            return false;
        }
    }

    async deletePost(slug) {
        try {
            await this.databases.deleteDocument(conf.appwriteDatabaseId, conf.appwriteCollectionId, slug)
            return true;
        } catch (error) {
            console.log("Appwrite service :: deletePost() :: ", error)
            return false;
        }
    }

    // storage service

    async uploadFile(file) {
        try {
            return await this.bucket.createFile(conf.appwriteBucketId, ID.unique(), file) // if error use uploadFile()
        } catch (error) {
            console.log("Appwrite service :: uploadFile() :: ", error)
            return false
        }
    }

    async deleteFile(fileId) {
        try {
            return await this.bucket.deleteFile(conf.appwriteBucketId, fileId)
        } catch (error) {
            console.log("Appwrite service :: deleteFile() :: ", error)
            return false
        }
    }

    getFilePreview(fileId) {
        return this.bucket.getFilePreview(conf.appwriteBucketId, fileId).href
    }
}

const service = new Service()
export default service;
```

Is there a way to fix this? It seems doesn't seem to recognize the new construct URL.

I have been following Hitesh Chowdary's YouTube Tutorial.

*https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zWF7O7aHQW4*